# Chrome driver exception: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: crashed

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm running python 3.12. Both chrome for testing and chrome driver are the same version i.e. 123.0.6312.58 - this has been checked and verified

It's working perfectly fine on my Mac. However when I run the dockerized app I get the error

```
024-03-20 19:53:58 03/20/2024 06:53:58PM - ERROR - helper_functions.py::helper_functions::__init__:36 - Chrome driver exception: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
2024-03-20 19:53:58   (disconnected: unable to connect to renderer)
2024-03-20 19:53:58   (The process started from chrome location /usr/local/bin/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
2024-03-20 19:53:58 Stacktrace:
2024-03-20 19:53:58 #0 0x555555cc9993 <unknown>
2024-03-20 19:53:58 #1 0x5555559c4136 <unknown>
2024-03-20 19:53:58 #2 0x5555559f8448 <unknown>
2024-03-20 19:53:58 #3 0x5555559f443d <unknown>
2024-03-20 19:53:58 #4 0x555555a3d239 <unknown>
```

My docker config looks like this

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ubuntu:20.04


ENV PATH /usr/local/bin:$PATH


RUN set -eux; \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        tzdata \
        wget \
        unzip \
    ;


RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get install -y python3.12
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN apt-get update &&  apt-get install -y libgbm1 gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 \
    libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget ca-certificates


RUN set -eux; \
    wget -O chrome-linux64.zip https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/123.0.6312.58/linux64/chrome-linux64.zip && \
    unzip chrome-linux64.zip && \
    mv chrome-linux64/* /usr/local/bin/ && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chrome && \
    rm -rf chrome-linux64.zip chrome-linux64


RUN set -eux; \
    wget -O chromedriver-linux64.zip https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/123.0.6312.58/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip && \
    unzip chromedriver-linux64.zip && \
    mv chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver && \
    rm -rf chromedriver-linux64.zip chromedriver-linux64


COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt


RUN mkdir /home/test
WORKDIR /home/test



COPY . .


ENTRYPOINT ["behave"]

CMD ["-v", "features/scenarios", "-D", "browser=chrome", "-f", "html", "-o", "test-results/report.html"]
```

Environment

- Selenium 4.18
- Ubuntu Linux Docker image
- Behave 1.2.7dev5